# How to access an item in an array embedded in another array with SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to access an Int in an array called "MemberID" but its located inside an array inside another array like this:

```
{
  "userMessage" : "ErnollmentSuccess",
  "data" : {
    "memberId" : 3635,
    "refreshToken" : "fc22418f1267488485e5f99a510b1618",
    "tokenType" : "bearer",
    "accessToken" : "1ce9744bd2604392adc0e896bba24f2a",
    "expiresIn" : 1209600
  }
```

Does anyone know how I can extract the memberID value?

Comment: json["data"]["memberId"]

Comment: That did it, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a json value of type JSON with the following content

```
{
  "userMessage" : "ErnollmentSuccess",
  "data" : {
    "memberId" : 3635,
    "refreshToken" : "fc22418f1267488485e5f99a510b1618",
    "tokenType" : "bearer",
    "accessToken" : "1ce9744bd2604392adc0e896bba24f2a",
    "expiresIn" : 1209600
}
```

You can write this

```
if let memberID = json["data"]["memberid"].int {
    print(memberID)
}
```